# It is possible to implement insertion sort for sorting linked list ?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting

it is possible to implement insertion sort for sorting linked lists ? will it have the same O(n^2) efficiency as the array version ?

Comment: What do you think.? Have you tried analysing hat may or may not work?

Comment: pls dont downwote am new to this

Comment: tried but i did get sorry fo asking this question am new to cs and this app also pls dont downwote my ques. tnx

Comment: When you are new, downvotes will not hurt you very much. So, you should just ignore it, or take it as an indication that there might be something to improve, and you always want to edit and improve. Downvoters are often mistaken too. I never downvote, because it is pointless, but I do make critical comments, because that is the way of science. In your case it would be betterto show that you worked, and have an opinion on the issue but wonder about some points, leaving room for people to comment other than by yes and no. Most people will try to help you. My comment was suggesting improvement.

Comment: Another point: make full sentences, with complete words. No SMS style.

Comment: thank you so much . its sounds good you are really a good person .yea i will keep improving myself ,can you please suggest me some good tips to improve my programming skills through this app. i am a second year computer science student

Comment: This is not intended for discussion (there is a chatroom for that, but you need to acquire some rep first). Furthermore, programming is not the tipic of this site. There are sites for that on stackexchange.com. Now my best advice is: try to understand programming techniques, proper use of programming languages, and also learn standard algorithms and data structure. If you have the opportunity, try to understand programs from very reputable programmers (but there are not so many that are really good). And recall rule 1: *programs must be easy to read and understand, by other programmers.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is fully answered by the [Wikipedia page on insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). In summary, yes, you can implement insertion sort on a linked list with the same efficiency as for an array because insertion sort only makes sequential accesses to the data being sorted. Every time it accesses the data, it's looking at "this element", "the next/previous element" or "that element I was looking at a few moments ago and whose index/position in the list I already stored."

Comment: thanx :) sorry for asking this question am new to stack exchange app